# i want to send notification to my all authenticated app user

Tags: java, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have an application that contains order data . I want to send this to all users of this app as notification.My target is to send Push Notifications to all of the users of my applications. How would I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

To begin with your app mush already be using GCM and listening to the correct topic. Otherwise you have to roll out an update with the new GCM feature and hope that all users update it.

If you want to see some code for this take a look at [this](https://github.com/CarlOhlsson/gcmTemplateApp) sample i crated some time ago. What you need to implement from the sample is the "SubscribeTopic" part. And to test if its working you can use [this](https://github.com/CarlOhlsson/gcmTemplateServer) java program.

The good thing about topics is that you don’t need to save the users registration tokens and the message is sent to everyone listening for that exact topic.

Comment: i cant understand from where to start..please guide me

Answer (score 0):

Use [Apache kafka](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#uses)

> The original use case for Kafka was to be able to rebuild a user
>   activity tracking pipeline as a set of real-time publish-subscribe
>   feeds. This means site activity (page views, searches, or other
>   actions users may take) is published to central topics with one topic
>   per activity type. These feeds are available for subscription for a
>   range of use cases including real-time processing, real-time
>   monitoring, and loading into Hadoop or offline data warehousing
>   systems for offline processing and reporting.

Answer (score 0):

To start with, note that a full GCM implementation requires both a client implementation and a server implementation. Before you can write client apps that use GCM, you must have an application server that meets the following criteria:

> - Able to communicate with your client.
> - Able to send properly formatted requests to the GCM connection
>     server.
> - Able to handle requests and resend them using exponential back-off.
> - Able to securely store the API key and client registration tokens.
>     Note: never include the API key in any client code.
> - For XMPP, the server must be able to generate message IDs to uniquely
>     identify each message it sends (GCM HTTP connection server generates
>     message IDs and returns them in the response). XMPP message IDs
>     should be unique per sender ID.

Complete documentation, how-to-guides for sending messages and links to examples can be found from [Cloud Messaging - Messaging Concepts and Options](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#components-of-a-message).

You may also check [ANDROID AND GCM – BROADCAST YOURSELF](http://avilyne.com/?p=267) for the tutorial and demonstration on the use of GCM for the broadcast of messages to an Android client from a Tomcat server and use of sending `broadcastintents` from a service and receiving those `broadcastintents` from an app's activity.